# AutoHotKey run command in background

Tags: autohotkey

I'm trying to run a command with AutoHotKey that I would normally run with cmd.exe. Here is the command:

```
pandoc -s "C:\input.txt" -o "D:\output.html"
```

This is how I do it in AutoHotKey:

```
#a::
run pandoc -s "C:\input.txt" -o "D:\output.html"
return
```

The only problem is that this opens up the a command prompt called "pandoc". Normally I'd just type in the command in cmd.exe and it would run without any hiccups or any windows opening. For this, however, that pandoc window shows up. Am I doing it correctly? Is there any easy way to suppress the window and run the command in the background?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Runs a program without opening a window.  The program is "cmd.exe", the windows command shell. It is invoked with arguments "/c time /t", which outputs the current time. It redirects the output to "c:\t.txt"

**program**

```
#a::
  run cmd /c time /t > c:\t.txt, c:\, hide
  return
```

**output**

```
c:\>type c:\t.txt
14:28
```

Comment: So I add a `, hide` after it? Doesn't seem to work for me. AHK gives me an error saying that the program/document can't be launched with my command... I also tried out your command, but I'm not sure what it does (I'm fairly new to this stuff)

Comment: You probably need to append `,,hide` to your line; hide is the third argument to the [Run](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/Run.htm) statement.

Comment: The answer isn't clear but the comment is. I confirm `,,hide` does work: `run C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /C   "C:\...\test.cmd" ,,hide`